# Pricing fixed coupon bond with ytm in QuantLib python

Tags: fixed-income, python, quantlib

I'm new to QuantLib and I'm confused about `ZeroCurve` in `YieldTermStructureHandle`

The start date is Oct 20, 2001. Assuming the evaluation date is May 8, 2017, and I can obtain the ytm, which is 4.3291. I think I can construct a flat yield curve and discount the cash flow. However, it says negative time (-0.452055) given.

```
from QuantLib import *
todaysDate = Date(8, 5, 2017)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate


spotDates = [Date(20, 4, 2017)+Period(i*6, Months) for i in range(1, 10)]
spotRates = [4.3291/100]*len(spotDates)

dayCount = ActualActual()
calendar = China()
interpolation = Linear()
compounding = Compounded
compoundingFrequency = 2

spotCurve = ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation, compounding, compoundingFrequency)
spotCurveHandle = YieldTermStructureHandle(spotCurve)

issueDate = Date(20, 10, 2001)
maturityDate = Date(20, 10, 2021)
tenor = Period(2)

bussinessConvention = Following
dateGeneration = DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False

schedule = Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, bussinessConvention, bussinessConvention, dateGeneration, monthEnd)


couponRate = 4.2/100
coupons = [couponRate]

settlementDays = 
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount)

bondEngine = DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurveHandle)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

fixedRateBond.NPV()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point in your rate curve needs to be the evaluation date, start with i = 0 and your evaluation date

`spotDates = [Date(8, 5, 2017)+Period(i*6, Months) for i in range(0, 10)]`